# Create Popup GUI that displays answer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, variables, popup

So Currently I have a code that is producing some variables in the Matlab workspace, which is fine and dandy, but I was wondering if there was a way to get these results to be displayed in a popup GUI?  I know i can create a GUI that displays options for input, but i just wanted to know if there's a way to do output as well.  thanks

currently I'm going at this in an undirect way

```
tap_total = evalin( 'base', 'tap_total' );
streaking = evalin( 'base', 'streaking' );
menu('Max Banding and Streaking',max(tap_total),max(streaking))
```

this is popping the results up in a menu for me, but a standard text box would work better.

Comment: depends on what type of data you want to display, For example you can use UITABLE function to display tabular data

Comment: @Amro One of them is a <5446x1 double> and the other is a <11x1 double>  after the edit in my quesiton, i show that im only looking for one value from each of these (the max value) to be displayed in a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
msgbox(str);
```

to display a message. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Would i be able to have it display a variable from my workspace though?  not a text string

Comment: Is the variable a number or a matrix? If so, use `num2str` or `mat2str`.

Comment: It's a matrix, is there a way to get the msg box to display 2 lines? as i have 2 variables i wish to be displayed.  And could i add a precursor of text to each?  like Streaking: 1.2525

Comment: Try this: `msgbox({sprintf('Max Banding:   %f',max(tap_total)) sprintf('Max Streaking: %f',max(streaking))})`